# PHP, Zend Framwork Errors getting consumed by Apache

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

I installed Apache2, PHP5 in a fresh Ubuntu system, Now I have uploaded a Zend Framework project, I see that the Zend and PHP errors are getting consumed by Apache and I am always getting a Internal Server Error 500 on the browser. When I looked into the error log of apache2 I find the PHP errors logged in there.

I have the error_reporting as E_ALL | E_STRICT, display_errors On in php.ini.

Comment: Often this errors occur due to wrong .htaccess settings

Comment: I saw PHP errors in the error.log file for apache2. Corrected them, and everything works fine. But I need the errors to be shown on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things worked after I set AllowOverride to All...

Answer (score 0):

By default ZF shows errors in development mode but hides them in production mode (this is a good thing). You can change these settings in application.ini. If you are having this problem in dev mode, ensure APPLICATION_ENV is being set correctly.